# Vuforia AR camera tracking 2 markers, and manually set focus to one moving marker on Android?

Tags: android, camera, unity-game-engine, setfocus, vuforia

I'm using Vuforia in Unity to track 2 AR markers (without a fixed spatial relationship), and 1 marker is always out of focus (when moving it). Therefore, I think the Vuforia multi-targets case doesn't apply to it well?

I'm thinking maybe to touch a screen and set the focus manually to the moving marker, but not quite sure if the fixed marker will still tracking well. I couldn't find a way in Unity to set focus area, but I found it's possible to do it by Android camera directly.

Is it possible to sill use Vuforia AR camera tracking 2 markers(without a fixed spatial relationship) and can manually set the focus of the camera to one marker? Or Metaio provide a solution? Thanks.

Comment: have you looked at [this](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-3-extension-technical-discussion/frame-marker-camera-focus) discussion? There is an interesting script that sets the focus mode. It seems your problem might have to do with auto_focus not working on your device.

Comment: I already set up the auto focus, and I don't think this is the same issue..

Comment: @sophia Do you have solution for this. I am stuck with same problem.